# angular 8 application calling Springboot application returns empty

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a Springboot application which returns a list of Courses http://localhost:8080/courses/ . I have an Angular application which calls the mentioned API in order to display those courses at frontend. I can confirm the springboot application is returning the values. But somehow my angular application can't seem to retrieve the same from the angular application. Below is the code.

**output of springboot app**

[{"_id":"5d29c3a58212eda90db024c4","courseID":"1","courseName":"C#"},{"_id":"5d29c3a58212eda90db024c5","courseID":"2","courseName":"Java"},{"_id":"5d29c3a58212eda90db024c6","courseID":"3","courseName":"JavaScript"}]

**courses.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoursesService {

  private baseURL = "/courses/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCoursesList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('${this.baseURL}');
  }

  deleteCourse(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseURL}/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
}
```

**course-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoursesService } from '../courses.service';
import { Courses } from '../courses';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-list',
  templateUrl: './course-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-list.component.css']
})
export class CourseListComponent implements OnInit {
  courses: Observable<Courses[]>;

  constructor(private coursesService: CoursesService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  reloadData() {
    this.courses = this.coursesService.getCoursesList();
  }

  deleteCourse(id: number) {
    this.coursesService.deleteCourse(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.reloadData();
        },
        error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

**course-list.component.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Courses</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Course ID</th>
          <th>Course Name</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let course of courses">
          <td>{{course.id}}</td>
          <td>{{course.courseId}}</td>
          <td>{{course.courseName}}</td>
          <td><button (click)="deleteEmployee(employee.id)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SpringBoot app controller**

```
package SpringBoot.Training.Management.Tool.SpringBootTMTCourses.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import SpringBoot.Training.Management.Tool.SpringBootTMTCourses.Model.Courses;
import SpringBoot.Training.Management.Tool.SpringBootTMTCourses.Repository.CoursesRepository;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/courses")
public class CourseController {
    @Autowired
    private CoursesRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Courses> getAllCourses() {
      return repository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Courses getCourseById(@PathVariable("id") ObjectId id) {
      return repository.findBy_id(id);
    }



      @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
      public void modifyCourseById(@PathVariable("id") ObjectId id, @Valid @RequestBody Courses pets) {
        pets.set_id(id);
        repository.save(pets);
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public Courses createPet(@Valid @RequestBody Courses pets) {
        pets.set_id(ObjectId.get());
        repository.save(pets);
        return pets;
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
      public void deletePet(@PathVariable ObjectId id) {
        repository.delete(repository.findBy_id(id));
      }

}
```

Comment: Hi @user21334, about the "courses.services.ts" Can you try changing the baseUrl to "http://localhost:8080/courses/" instead of only "/courses/". Also, your "course-list.component.ts" I can't see a call to reloadData() that calls the backend, shoudn't be inside the ngOnInit?

Comment: Is angular running development mode using ng serve ?

Answer (score 2):

The code below

```
  reloadData() {
    this.courses = this.coursesService.getCoursesList();
  }
```

should be

```
  reloadData() {
    this.coursesService.getCoursesList().subscribe((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
            this.courses =res;
        });
  }
```

The type of courses property should be:

```
courses: Courses[];
```

And then, call the reloadData() inside the ngOnInit() because the property it is not been set.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `courses`. Do that in your `ngOnInit`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoursesService } from '../courses.service';
import { Courses } from '../courses';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-list',
  templateUrl: './course-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-list.component.css']
})
export class CourseListComponent implements OnInit {
  courses: Observable<Courses[]>;

  constructor(private coursesService: CoursesService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData();  // HERE
  }

  reloadData() {
    this.courses = this.coursesService.getCoursesList();
  }

  deleteCourse(id: number) {
    this.coursesService.deleteCourse(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.reloadData();
        },
        error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

Now since the `this.coursesService.getCoursesList();` will return an `Observable`, you'll have to use an `async` pipe in the template in order to unwrap the value. Something like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Courses</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Course ID</th>
          <th>Course Name</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let course of courses | async">
          <td>{{course.id}}</td>
          <td>{{course.courseId}}</td>
          <td>{{course.courseName}}</td>
          <td><button (click)="deleteEmployee(employee.id)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```